# PHP is_scalar function

Tags: php

PHP question.

Is there ever a value of $foo for which is_scalar($foo) will not be the same as (is_numeric($foo) || is_bool($foo) || is_string($foo))

Thanks

Comment: According to the documentation - no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into this it appears this actual answer is ***no***

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**
is_scalar is a different function from is_bool, is_numeric and is_string etc. It tells you if given variable is scalar or not, so an int, bool, float or string will be scalar but an array and object won't.

It seems that (is_numeric($foo) || is_bool($foo) || is_string($foo)) can be replaced with is_scalar. But if you are looking to use it then my recommendation would be to see what's your usage. If you are interested in just a scalar value then it should be good enough, if you are interested in specific data types then you should go for the exact check.

More details can be seen here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-scalar.php

Comment: is_scalar('a b c') returns true

Comment: Lizard you are right, updating my answer. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Beenish Khan: have you even read the question? OP didn't ask to explain what documentation says about `is_scalar` or what scalar value ue

Comment: zerkms I read the question and answered it according to my understanding. I noted your answer above, if you can elaborate it then it would help us to learn something new here.

Comment: @Beenish Khan: the question was: "Is there ever a value of $foo for which is_scalar($foo) will not be the same as (is_numeric($foo) || is_bool($foo) || is_string($foo))". And you just explained how the functions work